# How to display Email meta data related fields in Windows Explorer on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, email, windows-explorer, microsoft-outlook-2016, metadata

How do I populate the Windows 10 Windows Explorer fields `From Address` and `From Addresses` detail view in Windows 10 when I have a directory full of `.msg` files from Outlook 2016?

[image: Directory of .msg files with empty From and From addresses fields in Windows Explorer on Windows 10]

Answer (score 0):

You may display the details of `.msg` files in the Explorer Preview pane.
To enable the Preview pane, click *View > Preview pane*.

Caveat: This will only work when the 32-bit version of Outlook is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research, Even when looking at the properties of the file I can only see the date I stored it on the disk and can no longer see any details of the messages itself such as date received and the name of the sender without first opening the message. You could follow the guidance to view [Msg-file details in Windows File Explorer](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/417).